# React/Redux: is it okay to access action payload in mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've got this mapDispatchToProps function for a MediaUpload component. Upon adding a file, the onChange handler is triggered. The handler dispatches two actions: first it creates new media entries for files and returns an array of media objects. Then it updates the form data in the state with an array of media ids.

My question is: is it okay to read the action data in this position or do we preferably write to state via a reducer first?

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, { form, name, multiple }) => ({
  onChange: files => {
  if (isEmpty(files)) return;

  return dispatch(createMedia(files)).then(
    media => {
      // Get created media ids from action payload. Is this correct?
      const mediaIds = media.map(item => item.payload.id);

      return dispatch(updateFormData({
        form,
        fields: [ {
          name: name,
          value: multiple ? mediaIds : mediaIds[0]
        } ]
      }));
    }
  );
}
```

});

Comment: I think this one will _probably_ be quite opinion based. I don't see any problem with this myself; Redux is going to handle this as a separate action and I don't think it matters how the data passed in the action got there. I might be missing something though, I'd be interested to hear if there are any potential problems with this.

Comment: Thanks @OliverRadini. I'm not aware of any potential problems, but since Redux is pretty strict in its dataflow this feels kind of wrong for some reason. Now that I think about it, maybe some middleware would be a better option.

Comment: IMO, this logic belongs in a thunk action or something similar. It would be a lot easier to do unit testing when it's not part of mapDispatchToProps. I think it's in the right place in terms of data flow, unless the mediaIds are being used by any components.

Comment: in situation like this, I always write middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a Redux maintainer.  Seems fine to me, assuming that `createMedia()` is itself a thunk action creator that returns a promise.

That said, I also recommend moving that function definition to be standalone, and using [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) rather than the function form.